# Why Laravel is not returning the relationship records of a specific user (It returns records of all the users)?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

This is a very weird situation. I don't know if it's some issue with my understanding or a bug in Laravel Eloquent ORM. But here's what is happening.

I have one table called `users` and another called `user_metas`. One table contains all the user data obviously and the another table (user_metas) has 4 columns as follows.

- id
- user_id
- name
- value

Now, there are 4 records in this table that I want to fetch **FOR A SPECIFIC USER**. They are as follows.

- name => region_name
- name => region_code
- name => country_name
- name => country_code

I have a `hasMany` and `belongsTo` relationship defined in `User.php` and `UserMeta.php` respectively. And here is how I am trying to fetch the above given rows from a `user_metas` table.

```
$user->meta()->where('name','like','region%')->orWhere('name','like','country%')->pluck('value','name');
```

The problem is, It is returning all the records that match `region%` and `country%` from the whole freaking table even though I have requested the data for a specific user only! It should filter out other records automatically!

I don't know what's wrong. Maybe I misunderstood the feature or something's up with Eloquent ORM. Can anyone spread some knowledge here?

**Update:** using `toSql` function, I figured out that it is using conditions directly instead of grouping them. It means, the condition is like this `user_id = ? AND name = ? OR name = ?` instead of `user_id = ? AND (name = ? or name = ?)`.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I figured it out! The only thing I had to do is to pass a closure to the where function and write down the conditions. Here is my old code and the new code that is working.

Old code:

```
$user->meta()->where('name','like','region%')->orWhere('name','like','country%')->pluck('value','name');
```

New Code:

```
$user->meta()->where(function($q){
     $q->where('name','like','country%')
       ->orWhere('name','like','region%');
})->pluck('value','name');
```

And things worked out the way I wanted! Laravel always has perfect solutions!